# IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet (while deploying a Spring Boot project in a JBoss WildFly environment)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server, wildfly

This is my error message:

`IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`

In my opinion, the primary error appears to be this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
10:12:12,897 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to startservicejboss.deployment.unit.component."javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.component."javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectionTargets.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1235)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.checkDeclaringClassLoadable(Reflections.java:427)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.get(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:177)
    ... 12 more
```

**My jboss-deployment-structure.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <!-- exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="tomcat-embed-core"/>
            <module name="org.apache.juli"/>
            <module name="org.apache.juli.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**My build.gradle is:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

description = ''

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'


    // -- DATABASE start
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.32'
    // -- DATABASE end


    implementation "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper"

    implementation 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:3.0.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:3.0.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:3.0.8'

    implementation 'com.navercorp.lucy:lucy-xss-servlet:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.navercorp.lucy:lucy-xss:1.6.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '2.8.0', ext: 'pom'

    // log4j
    implementation 'org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2:log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1:1.16'
    // logback
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    implementation 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.1'

    providedRuntime 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    //junit
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2")

    //ioutil
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.13.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.4' /* Apache Commons FileUpload */

}
```

Comment: You're for unclear reason deploying a Spring Boot application as WAR to a Jakarta EE server instead of executing it as a normal Spring Boot JAR. You should then remove the embedded Tomcat server. Apparently you merely wanted to use Spring MVC/JDBC, in that case you don't necessarily need the whole Spring Boot parent for this.